# Android Firebase db datasnapshot pulling information from wrong db directory

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Android app I am using Google Firebase to store information in the database.

I need to iterate through the information, and below for-loop is being used

```
public void showDataLobReq(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){

    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.child("Lobby_Requests").getChildren()){
        System.out.println("asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf"+ds.getValue());
        game = ds.child(userID).child("game").getValue(String.class);
        console = ds.child(userID).child("console").getValue(String.class);
        mic = ds.child(userID).child("mic").getValue(String.class);
        players = ds.child(userID).child("players").getValue(String.class);
    }


}
```

You may notice that I put '.child("Lobby_Requests")' after dataSnapshot. this is because the dataSnapshot takes a snapshot of the whole database, so I must go into the subdirectory "Lobby_Requests" because that is where the information I need to iterate through is.

Putting this '.child()' in is being problematic.

I print to the console what the dataSnapshot contains in the first line of the for loop and with .child("Lobby_Requests") it is pulling information from the directory "Lobbies" in the actual database, which is a completely different directory.

Yet, when I remove the '.child()' completely it gives me a view of the whole database like it should. Why is it doing this?

Code for listener:

```
nRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
    nRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                showDataLobReq(dataSnapshot);
            } else {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Here is JSON:

```
{


"Games" : {
    "Forza 6" : {
      "Consoles" : {
        "PC" : true,
        "Xbox 1" : true,
        "Xbox 360" : true
      },
      "FilePathName" : "forza6",
      "Genres" : {
        "Racing" : true
      },
      "Live Lobbies" : 0,
      "Name" : "Forza 6"
    },
    "Minecraft" : {
      "Consoles" : {
        "PC" : true,
        "Xbox 1" : true,
        "Xbox 360" : true
      },
      "FilePathName" : "minecraft",
      "Genres" : {
        "Adventure" : true,
        "Creation" : true,
        "Open World" : true
      },
      "Live Lobbies" : 0,
      "Name" : "Minecraft"
    }
  },
  "Lobbies" : {
    "Cd6lVd2XMUYoLH6b0xoHsrfXMud2" : {
      "Messages" : {
        "-Kq6-1HsMvElEXZZyCIk" : {
          "messageText" : "hey",
          "messageTime" : 1501208519771,
          "messageUser" : ""
        }
      },
      "console" : "Origin",
      "game" : "Minecraft",
      "leader" : "Cd6lVd2XMUYoLH6b0xoHsrfXMud2",
      "mic" : "Mic",
      "note" : "2345",
      "players" : "4"
    },
    "KUWH5f1TmYfO1O1wgCJLli3XZFi2" : {
      "console" : "Steam",
      "game" : "Forza 6",
      "mic" : "No Mic",
      "note" : "Hey Join Here!",
      "players" : "2"
    },
    "hpWkq0D8clPReUetOq9Xtmc4V582" : {
      "Messages" : {
        "-Kq5a0kX305lFCRTSM_G" : {
          "messageText" : "hello",
          "messageTime" : 1501201701014,
          "messageUser" : ""
        },
        "-Kq5asufOWQwtmyNJrQ7" : {
          "messageText" : "hey",
          "messageTime" : 1501201926941,
          "messageUser" : ""
        }
      },
      "console" : "Xbox One",
      "game" : "Minecraft",
      "leader" : "hpWkq0D8clPReUetOq9Xtmc4V582",
      "mic" : "Mic",
      "note" : "kjhg",
      "players" : "4"
    }
  },
  "Lobby_Requests" : {
    "Cd6lVd2XMUYoLH6b0xoHsrfXMud2" : {
      "Cd6lVd2XMUYoLH6b0xoHsrfXMud2" : {
        "console" : "Xbox One",
        "game" : "Forza 6",
        "mic" : "Mic",
        "players" : "5"
      }
    },
    "KUWH5f1TmYfO1O1wgCJLli3XZFi2" : {
      "KUWH5f1TmYfO1O1wgCJLli3XZFi2" : {
        "console" : "Steam",
        "game" : "Forza 6",
        "mic" : "No Mic",
        "players" : "2"
      }
    },
    "hpWkq0D8clPReUetOq9Xtmc4V582" : {
      "hpWkq0D8clPReUetOq9Xtmc4V582" : {
        "console" : "Xbox One",
        "game" : "Minecraft",
        "mic" : "Mic",
        "players" : "4"
      },
      "players" : "4"
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "8cHrNCybwjO3PIUKxyOLiAqxJBv1" : {
      "gamertag" : "thedylan",
      "uname" : "thedood"
    },
    "Cd6lVd2XMUYoLH6b0xoHsrfXMud2" : {
      "gamertag" : "dmdylan",
      "uname" : "ninja goat"
    },
    "KUWH5f1TmYfO1O1wgCJLli3XZFi2" : {
      "gamertag" : "skaner",
      "uname" : "asdf"
    },
    "YvYEIiCBUSYKTviVyWpLHdyDIFw1" : {
      "gamertag" : "joejoe",
      "uname" : "Jifflingly"
    },
    "ZmX9yIZ6MNguQa1S3MaYNcxfK2b2" : {
      "gamertag" : "dmkaner",
      "uname" : "dmkaner"
    },
    "hpWkq0D8clPReUetOq9Xtmc4V582" : {
      "gamertag" : "dmkaner",
      "uname" : "dmkaner"
    },
    "t21ncnuRmeV4F7RknETBisMrxS42" : {
      "gamertag" : "asdf",
      "uname" : "asdf"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of firebase listener for the path "Lobby_Requests"?

Comment: @Mani There ya go

Comment: I doubt your instantiation of firebase         
Firebase firebase = new Firebase("YOUR_PATH_TOFIREBASE_LOCATION");

Comment: Please edit your question to include the minimal JSON that is needed to reproduce the problem (likely just one child is enough). Please share as text, not as a screenshot. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen there ya go

Comment: @Mani what do you mean

Comment: Why are you using `.child()` at all? You can update the `DatabaseReference` to use `serverName/Lobby_Requests`

Comment: @cricket_007 because in the code in my actual project the listener calls another method that need to use a different part of the the database so I must focus in on that post databaseReference instantiation

Comment: You can have multiple DatabaseReference objects. One called `root`, another called `lobbyRequests`

Comment: @cricket_007 I did at one point and the exact same problem was occuring

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you are **pushing your data twice** and there is no need for this.

```
  "Lobby_Requests" : {
      "Cd6lVd2XMUYoLH6b0xoHsrfXMud2" : {
          "Cd6lVd2XMUYoLH6b0xoHsrfXMud2" : { //This is wrong
```

If you'll change the way in which you add data to the Firebase database by pushing that data **only once**, your code will work for fine. Your database should look like this:

```
"Lobby_Requests" : {
  "Cd6lVd2XMUYoLH6b0xoHsrfXMud2" : {
    "console" : "Xbox One",
    "game" : "Forza 6",
    "mic" : "Mic",
    "players" : "5"
  },
```

As  you probably see, there is only one pushed key.

Comment: This is not the problem, actually I manually pushed the data twice in hopes of solving this problem. The problem persisted even when data was only pushed once.

Comment: If you have childrens either with one or either with two pushed ids in the same location, it will not work. Can you please update your database structure as it is now? Because you code should work. Does not contain anything wrong.

Comment: @dylan: While your code might also not have worked when you had only one push ID, it definitely won't work with having it twice. Even if doing what Alex says doesn't completely solve your problem, it will at least get closer to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).